# Libfreenect driver on ros

Tags: ros, kinect, libfreenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone tell me how to use libfreenect driver on ros with a python script? I am using kinect

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274541/libfreenect-driver-on-ros/) by [tsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/32438/tsw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once you launch the driver, many topics will be published (point clouds, depth maps, RGB images, etc.). To work with these topics in Python, you simply need to subscribe to the correct topic and perform the desired processing in the callback. Check out the rospy tutorials for instructions on how to create Subscribers: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Tutorials

One note: the Kinect produces a lot of data. You may find it difficult to write Python code that can keep up (especially if you are working with the point clouds). In my experience, most people that use the Kinect do most of their processing in C++, and they usually use PCL.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0